# Animate scrolling of UIScrollView with CoreAnimation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, core-animation

Sorry for a big question, real question are **bold** in bottom, now some explanation.

I'm use CoreAnimation in my project for animate some objects moving like this.

```
CABasicAnimation *moveAnimation;        
moveAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];      
moveAnimation.duration = 2.0;       
moveAnimation.repeatCount=1;        
moveAnimation.autoreverses=NO;  
moveAnimation.delegate = self;
moveAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:[crawler.layer position]];
moveAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
moveAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
CGPoint p;
moveAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
[crawler.layer addAnimation:moveAnimation forKey:@"moveAnimation"];
```

And now I need to animate scrolling of some UIScrollView. I can't use `setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated` method, because it can't customise animation duration.

I can make it like this

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x + 200, scrollView.contentOffset.y);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

but it's not CoreAnimation, and using 2 different kinds of animation techniques in one app is not a good practice, I think.

**Is there a way to use a CoreAnimation to animate scrolling of UIScrollView content to custom point with custom animation duration?**
P.S. Sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should read about animatable properties, [Programming iOS 5](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html)

Indeed, when you try to animate layers, Apple gives a set of animatable properties, but you're not limited to this set. You can animate whatever you want.

In all cases, you shouldn't use `kCAFillModeForwards` because it will ask the device to redraw forever the last presentation layer that was used for the animation, instead of using a cached representation of the layer.

So the way you could achieve such a thing would be by defining a specific layer of yours where the `contentOffset` property is defined as animatable. And in order to work, you should start by verifying what kind of top layer class is used by a scrollview, so that, by subclassing it and setting the wanted property (`contentOffset`) animatable, and subclassing your scrollview by setting this layer as the top layer of the scrollview, you could possibly achieve what you're trying to do.

This is theory!

But this is what I would try.
Look for this method and its behavior and intents

```
+ (BOOL)needsDisplayForKey:(NSString *)key
```

Another thing you could read is this [A start example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016496/why-animating-custom-calayer-properties-causes-other-properties-to-be-nil-during). But this also means you should redraw your uiscrollview by yourself!

Comment: Thank's a lot. This is what I need to now.

Answer (score 28):

You could use:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^ {
    [scrollView setContentOffset:destination animated:NO];
}];
```

You can set the duration of the animation this way.

Comment: Yes, I can,but this is block animation, not CoreAnimation, isn't it? I need a way to use CoreAnimation for this because already use it in project and don't want to use 2 different techniques.

Comment: Wonderfully simple answer to the duration part of the question.

Comment: "block animation" is just a wrapper around Core Animation, not a different technology. you can mix 'em freely.

Answer (score 7):

```
[UIScrollViewNameHere setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x value of where you want to move to, y value of where you want to move to) animated:YES];
```

for example:

```
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 2, 2341, 412)];
[scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320, 0) animated:YES];
```

Comment: I can't use setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated method, because it can't customise animation duration. i write it in question, read it closely.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think so that you can animate the point with CoreAnimation.

But you can try `setContentOffset:animated:` thats the method you are searching for?

You can transform only following properties of `UIView`

- frame
- bounds
- center
- transform
- alpha
- backgroundColor
- contentStretch

more Information of the `CoreAnimation` about animation checkout the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but setContentOffset:animated: method not situable in my situation, because i need to set animation duration. And your link is not for CoreAnimation) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html This is documentation about it.