# Animating UIScrollView Scrolling

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, core-animation

Took me weeks to figure out this simple trick, so let me try out this Q&A format.

How do you animate the scrolling of a UIScrollView with CoreAnimation? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409231/animate-scrolling-of-uiscrollview-with-coreanimation) is overly complex, though it does provide a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Simple!

To use Core Animation, you have to modify a property of a UIView's underlying CALayer. Turns out, when you scroll a UIScrollView, all you're really doing is modifying the CALayer's `bounds` property (specifically the `origin.y` component). Hence, this code will do the trick:

```
NSString *keyPath = @"bounds.origin.y";
[self.scrollView.layer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0] forKeyPath:keyPath];

CABasicAnimation *bounceAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:keyPath];
bounceAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:100];
bounceAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
bounceAnimation.duration = 2.0f;

[self.scrollView.layer addAnimation:bounceAnimation forKey:@"someKey"];
```